# Django: remove GROUP BY added with extra() method?

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, photologue

Hi (excuse me for my bad english) !

When I make this:

```
gallery_qs = Gallery.objects.all()\
                    .annotate(Count('photos'))\
                    .extra(select={'photo_id': 'photologue_photo.id'})
```

The sql query is :

```
SELECT (photologue_photo.id) AS `photo`, `photologue_gallery`.*
FROM `photologue_gallery` 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `photologue_gallery_photos` 
      ON (`photologue_gallery`.`id` = `photologue_gallery_photos`.`gallery_id`) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `photologue_photo` 
      ON (`photologue_gallery_photos`.`photo_id` = `photologue_photo`.`id`) 
GROUP BY `photologue_gallery`.`id`, photologue_photo.id 
ORDER BY `photologue_gallery`.`publication_date` DESC
```

The problem is that `extra` method automatically adds photologue_photo.id in GROUP BY clause. And I need remove it, because it duplicates galleries, for example :

```
[<Gallery: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet>, <Gallery: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet>, <Gallery: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet>, <Gallery: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet>, <Gallery: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet>, <Gallery: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet>, <Gallery: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet>]
```

Si I need to make this query with django, is it possible ?

```
SELECT (photologue_photo.id) AS `photo`, `photologue_gallery`.*
FROM `photologue_gallery` 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `photologue_gallery_photos` 
      ON (`photologue_gallery`.`id` = `photologue_gallery_photos`.`gallery_id`) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `photologue_photo` 
      ON (`photologue_gallery_photos`.`photo_id` = `photologue_photo`.`id`) 
GROUP BY `photologue_gallery`  
ORDER BY `photologue_gallery`.`publication_date` DESC
```

Thank you ! :)

Comment: As far as i see, the query won't work when you remove it from GROUP_BY. If it is in SELECT, it's required be present in GROUP_BY.

Comment: I use the second query and it works. Why not ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you really need the extra.  From Django's concept, you don't need to cherry pick specific columns while running a Django QuerySet.  That logic can be done in the template side.

I assume you know how to push `galley_qs` to your template from your view:

```
# views.py
gallery_qs = Gallery.objects.all()\
                .annotate(Count('photos'))
```

In your template/html:

```
{% for gallery in gallery_qs %}
    {% for photo in gallery.photos %}

    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

`photos` is your ManyToManyField in your gallery model.

Comment: I don't need to do this in my template but in my view, because I want select galleries and *one* photo according to the user's status (for example I need to select galleries with one public photo for visitors. So I need to exclude galleries without any public photo to display for visitors.)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to get distinct gallery records with a photo_id annotated on them when gallery to photo ids is a many to many relationship? From what I can tell, the query you are doing would only get a single photo id for each gallery.

If you really do need to do the above, I think you could use distinct() to get distinct gallery records (btw, you don't need the "all()" in there).

```
Gallery.objects.distinct()\
               .annotate(Count('photos'))\
               .extra(select={'photo_id': 'photologue_photo.id'})
```

Or you could just simply access the photo id directly,

```
g = Gallery.objects.annotate(Count('photos'))
# Get the photo
photo = g.photos[0]
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried using distinct(), but I always duplicated galleries like this : 

``[<Gallery: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet>, <Gallery: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet>, <Gallery: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet>, <Gallery: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet>, <Gallery: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet>, <Gallery: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet>, <Gallery: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet>]
``